# Automatically clear cache of the parent page

Tags: typo3, typo3-8.x

In TYPO3 how could I automatically clear the cache of the parent page, when one of its children pages' content is edited?

Let's imagine this page tree:

```
+ Root
|-+ A
  |-+ AA
  |-+ AB
```

I would like the cache of page 'A' automatically cleared, when the content (tt_content table) of page 'AB' is edited. Without using explicit page ids.

As far as documented the Page TSConfig setting

```
TCEMAIN.clearCacheCmd
```

only takes a list of explicit page ids, or the keywords "all", "pages", or cache tags
(see https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TSconfigReference/PageTsconfig/TceMain.html#clearcachecmd)
None of them lets you generically select the parent of the current page.

How could this be accomplished?

Comment: You will clear a lot of pages caches. Why do want to do this?

Comment: In this case, 'A' displays all of its children's content, whereas 'AA' and 'AB', although managed as pages in the backend, are never queried or displayed directly in the frontend.

Comment: Like 'A' is a presentation, built by slides 'AA' and 'AB'. I would like the presentation updated, when a slide (or more specific: the content of a slide) changes.